# compute average inside a while-loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, while-loop, mean

so I have this code:

```
def run_simulation(nba = 100, maxIter = 10, probI = 0.2, probR = 0.2, probI_init = 0.1, network = nx.erdos_renyi_graph, netParam=0.1, rep=10):
r = 0
while r < rep:
    init(nba, probI)
    i = 0
    while i < maxIter:
        step(probR, probI)
        nbI = collect_statistics()
        if nbI == 0:
            break
        i = i + 1
    print(statS[-1])
    r = r +1

run_simulation()
```

this code yields 10 numbers like this:

[image: Python code]

My question is: is there a way to compute the average of those 10 numbers and how?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since `statS` is clearly a global list being created and modified outside of this routine, it's a little hard to tell, but the OBVIOUS answer is to `print(sum(statS)/len(statS))` after the loop exits.

Comment: hi yes statS is a list. I need to compute the average of the last number of this list each time I run the simulation, which are those 10 numbers appeared in that simulation on the screenshot. so I'd have to write: print(sum(statS[-1])/len(statS)), however, it shows this error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: You cannot take the sum of a single value. Put in the whole list.

Comment: "average of the last number of the list" doesn't mean anything.  One number doesn't have an average, which is what it's telling you.  I ASSUME you really want to print the last number, and then print the average of all the numbers so far.  The line I included in my answer will do exactly that.